# passing by reference is getting error in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
 int passingByValue(int);
 int  passingByRef(int&);
 int main(){

    int rah = 51;
    int value = passingByValue(rah);
    int har =52;
   int ref = passingByRef(har&);

    cout<<"passing by value is = "<<value<<endl;
    cout<<"passing by ref is = "<<ref<<endl;

        system("pause");

}

  int passingByValue(int ol){
   return ol * ol;
 }
 int passingByRef(int *x){
    return *x=100;
  }
```

its simple function passing by value and passing by reference but i am getting an error whenever i passed by reference error is 11  31  D:\c++ programing practise\prog21.cpp   [Error] expected primary-expression before ')' token

Comment: I don't know what you think `har&` does, but it's *not* doing it. Just pass `har`. And btw, your prototype and implementation don't match.

Answer (score 3):

Your pass by reference function definition should look as follows:

```
 int passingByRef(int &x){
    return x=100;
  }
```

also you should call it without using address of operator: `&`

```
int ref = passingByRef(har);
```

Your current code for passing by reference looks more like code for pass by pointer.